# change the table data based on the selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table displaying data from the database. I have a select box where the person can select the currency in which he wants the data to be displayed.

When he does so, i need the data to be refreshed and displayed as the new currency. And I can't figure out how to do so without refreshing the whole page.

Any ideas please?

```
<select id="currency">
<option value = "rub">В рублях</option>
<option value = "usd">USD</option>
<option value = "eur">EURO</option>
</select>
<table id="servers" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
 <tr>
<td width="400"><b>Сервер</b></td>
<td width="100"><b>1 кк адены</b></td>
<td width="100"><b>1 ккк адены</b></td>
</tr>
<?php 
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `prices`");
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
echo("\t\t<tr>\n");
echo("\t\t\t<td>".$r['name']."</td>\n");
echo("\t\t\t<td>$".round($r['kk']/$dollar, 2)."</td>\n");
echo("\t\t\t<td>$".round($r['kkk']/$dollar, 2)."</td>\n");
echo("\t\t</tr>\n");
} ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can hold factors for data transformation (for conversion USD>AUS USD>EUR or whatever) you can delegate the change throughout the table by using one general selector.

first you place all the factors in the js vars like this(this must be doe inside php file and other stuff can be done in separated js):

```
var USDtoEUR = <?php echo $php2eur; ?>
```

Next thing you do, you bind event to click on the select box, button or whatever, let's say it is select with id "currency":

```
$('#currency'). click(function() {
 switch ($('this').val()) {
   case 'EUR' {
      //Code we will discuss is going here
   }
   break;
//... etc...
```

So, we want to change all the data we are assuming is in USD on click, so we have all the factors to convert from usd to other values stored in separate vars USDtoXXX. Note that we need one USDtoUSD, too.

Now... Whatever the structure is, the element containing dynamically changed data should have class and inusd attributes like this:

```
<li class="price" inusd="123">123</li>
```

th price in usd should be stored to an attribute to keep it independant from the dom content that will change.

so for the above example we do this:

```
$('.price').each(function() {
  $(this).text()=$(this).attr('inusd')*USDtoEUR;  //If user selected EUR
}
```

Be carefull to use breaks and default in the switch statement... javascript switch lets cases drop their conditions through.

Also, when working with money, please do the in depth testing of the calculating functions, javascript can mess that upp, too, from time to time :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use Ajax, which allows to request the DB and retrieve the data without refreshing the whole page.

Here is an introduction : http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_intro.asp

Then, have a look to  the jquery API and take a look at the examples : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Good luck

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i would like something a bit more concrete as to which methods/functions i should use